# Cannot refresh subform from other subform

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form that has multiple subforms on it.  When someone changes a value in a combobox of one of the subforms it needs to refresh another subform.  I am using this code but it doesn't work:

```
Forms!frmDispatchPlanningSheet!subfrmExtraDriversForPlanning.Form.Requery
```

I have even tried to remove the Record Source and re-add it.  However, that also did not work.

When I am saying it doesn't work for the direct requery, I don't get an error; it just doesn't requery.

For the remove and re-add the Record Source, it does remove and re-add the source; however, it still doesn't refresh the query.

however, when I click in the other form and then hit refresh all in the Ribbon, it will refresh (so I know the query works).

What am I doing wrong? how do I fix this?

Comment: You don't need .form.requery, try just .requery

Comment: I tried that but I need to change the combobox twice.  So if I choose DriverA, I need to choose DriverA then click on the combobox and choose DriverA again for it to refresh.  It seems like it is not saving earlier enough.  I put this in the AfterUpdate for the combobox; I tried to put that in the AfterUpdate event for the form and it doesn't even fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `subfrmExtraDriversForPlanning` refers to `Driver` via the table, you need to save the record first.

Add

```
Me.Dirty = False
```

before doing the `.Requery`.

Comment: That fixed it Andre